# Extend Hydra search context to generate filter fields client side?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, hydra-core

I'm using API Platform 3.1. When you've got an entity with a `ApiFilter`, Hydra will give some information about all fields with a filter. In this simple example it will give the name of the field (`createdAt`):

```
class Entity
{
  #[ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties: ['createdAt'])]
  protected ?DateTimeInterface $createdAt = null;
}
```

```
'hydra:search': { 
  "@type": "hydra:IriTemplate"
  "hydra:mapping": {
    "@type": "IriTemplateMapping",
    "variable": "createdAt[after]",
    "property": "createdAt",
    "required": false
  }
}
```

This information can be used to populate search fields client side, like Swagger does:
[image: Swagger example]

Now I want this information to generate a form with fields that can be used to sort or filter. But I want not only the field names, but some extra information about how the filter can be used. For example: a date field `createdAt` should render a slightly different datepicker than a `birthdate` field.

I've already tried extending the Hydra context as described in [API Platform's documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extending-jsonld-context/#hydra):

```
#[ApiResource(operations: [
    new Get(hydraContext: ['foo' => 'bar'])
])
```

But I didn't found foo/bar in my `/api/items` response.

Is there a way to add some information to the Hydra model which I can use in my application?